# How to override link color and margins/padding on buttons in twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First post here. I'm trying to override the link colors for Bootstrap buttons, but I can't get it to work. I actually got the background color to change, but I can't get the link colors to change. I also can't figure out how to space the buttons out more.

```
<span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><a href="#">Resume</a></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"> <a href="#">Twitter</a></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><a href="#">LinkedIn</a></button>
</span>

My css currently looks like:
.btn{
    background-color:#d0d0d0;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the text colour of the BootStrap buttons, you'll actually have to target the `<a>` element inside of the `.btn`. For example:

```
.btn a{
    color:#000;
}
```

This would change button link text to black. Hope this helped, let me know if you have any questions!