# Changing the color of Bootstrap anchor element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

I am having trouble changing the color of an anchor element that Bootstrap sets as  blue. I've tried this:

```
#about{
  color:white !important;
}
```

And this:

```
body div#more a#about{
  color:white;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="intro">
      <header class="header">
        <h1 class="my-name">Joe Schmo</h1>
        <div class="webdev">
          <span>&#123;   Web Developer </span><span>| St. Louis &#125;  
          </span>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="more" id="more">
        <a class="aboutme" id="#about" href="#about">About me</a>
        <a class="arrow fa fa-arrow-down" href="#about"></a>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Can you include the `html` codes too?

Comment: put your html code

Comment: Better define a class of your desired color and then put your CSS on that.
Or maybe if you want all your markups with Anchor links (#), you can try some CSS hacks like - 
`a[href^='#']`{
color: #FFF;
}

Comment: Also refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432768/how-to-override-link-color-and-margins-padding-on-buttons-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Oh, just figured it out. The id should be "about" instead of "#about" in the html.

Comment: Call your style sheet after bootstrap's style sheet in html page

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/dgcxd3gy/

```css
.aboutme {
  color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

.aboutme:hover{
  color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="intro">
      <header class="header">
        <h1 class="my-name">Joe Schmo</h1>
        <div class="webdev">
          <span>&#123;   Web Developer </span><span>| St. Louis &#125;  
          </span>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="more" id="more">
        <a class="aboutme" id="#about" href="#about">About me</a>
        <a class="arrow fa fa-arrow-down" href="#about"></a>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Just **target** an element with **class** or **id**. I have used **class**.

Even you can target an element by

```
a[herf="#about"] {
   color: red;
}
```